# facing problem with keyboard, buttons exchanged

Tags: keyboard

I'm using an HP Pavilion CORE i5 laptop. I am facing a problem with my keyboard as some buttons are interchanged! Like pressing the `#` button displays `\` and vice versa.

Comment: How exactly is this related to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Your keyboard is on the UK setting, not the US setting. I've had this problem before, as well as others. This is actually a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your keyboard settings aren't properly configured.

1. run `sudo raspi-config`
2. Choose `Internationalization menu`
3. Choose `Keyboard setup menu`
4. Select the proper layout. Note: English (US) and English (UK) are not interchangeable!